# C# Regular expression doesn't return matches

Tags: c#, regex

When i'm using javascript regex, it works fine, but Regex.Matches returns me only
1 match, the initial string.

Here is regex

```
(\d+)(?:\s*)(?:([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\.([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\.([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))(?:\s*)(?:\w*)(?:\s*)(.*)
```

And here is sample string, that i try to parse

```
  50    0000.74b9.ed90    DYNAMIC     Gi0/20
```

Comment: What did match? And what should match?

Comment: I expect to have 5 matches: 50, 0000, 74b9, ed90, Gi0/20

Comment: See my answer. it will give you the 5 matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use Match instead of matches.
The index [0] is the whole match.

```
Regex.Match("50    0000.74b9.ed90    DYNAMIC     Gi0/20", @"(\d+)(?:\s*)(?:([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\.([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\.([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))(?:\s*)(?:\w*)(?:\s*)(.*)").Groups[1].ToString()

Regex.Match(input,regex).Groups[1].ToString()
Regex.Match(input,regex).Groups[2].ToString()
Regex.Match(input,regex).Groups[3].ToString()
....
```

Comment: With Regex.Matches i get initial string as match, and i expect to have 5 matches, like it does in javascript or preg_match_all in php

Comment: you will get the five matches at the GROUPS collection.